# problem with adapting the size of my image with that of its layout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I have a problem with adapting the size of my image with that of its layout.

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android: gravity = "center" android: layout_height = "fill_parent"
            android: id = "@ + id / layoutImgSplash" android: visibility = "gone">
            <ImageView android: id = "@ + id / splash" android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
                    android: layout_height = "wrap_content" android: visibility = "gone" />
    </ LinearLayout>
```

the problem is: when I use an emulator like 240px wide, my layout is 240px wide as normal, because he has fill_parent in width parameters,
and the image that I download and I display it in my layout was like width: 320px,
So when viewing it lies ( hides ) to the left and right

I want to adjust (resize or something else ...) so it does not exceed 240px.
plz help me :(

Thank you in advance friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting scaleType to fitXY?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use one of the "scaleType" attributes, e.g. `android:scaleType="fitStart"`. There are many more options, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: thanks for your help , i will try this , and i will inform you about the result :)

Comment: that's not work :( ,  the real size of my image is : 320 in width, and when i try to execute my application on an emulator which have 240px on width, the image is hidden from the left and from the right , i want to display my image with 240 Px in width without hidding from left & right

Comment: Yep, from your explanation I was not sure which type of scaling you were trying to do, which is why I just linked to the scale docs.